# Adding new permission group android

Tags: java, android, android-framework

I am working on a project to provide a certain sharing capabilities in android devices. for this i have created a system service. Now when the service is invoked in the application it basically gets the permission as set by the developer in AndroidManifest.xml. Now my service works on the context of the application. I want the service to share some data through bluetooth/ wifi. For this i assume there are two approaches-

1. To create a new permission group and modifying the PackageManager to understand this new permission set.
2. Instead of passing the application context using a Global system context(something like a root user). I am not sure about this. if i am allowed to do this or not. 
       `public DataSharingService(Context context) {    super();    this.mContext = context;}`

   Can i initialize this.mContext in some other manner to achieve this and have different set of permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to create a custom system service. This service will run in the context of SystemServer so it will receive permissions to do almost everything. Then, in your applications you can use this service (but you need to update SDK for that).

Comment: The service does get launched by SystemServer so idealy it shud have all permissions but turns out when the application calls that service instance it gets the application context.

Comment: I find out that this is your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055477/system-server-and-application-permisions/13192859 I explained how to solve problem there.