# System server and application permisions

Tags: java, android, android-framework

I have written a system server/service in android framework. As far as i know it has the system level permissions. But when i call this  service using an app i get the permissions of application calling that service. Could anyone explain this behaviour? Also how could i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

When in your service you try to call method from other service, try to put the code of call into the following code block:

```
long token = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
//your call
Binder.restoreCallingIdentity(token);
```